# TextView is not displayed on SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-studio

I have SurfaceView set to display camera. On top of it I like to display a TextView.
My xml is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/preview_display_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">        
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gestureView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="hello"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

SurfaceView is setup to display camera on it. Then TextView is added after SurfaceView. Camera is displayed but TextView is not displayed on top of it. My code is as follows.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private static final boolean FLIP_FRAMES_VERTICALLY = true;    
    private SurfaceTexture previewFrameTexture;    
    private SurfaceView previewDisplayView;   
    private EglManager eglManager;
    private TextView gestureView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        previewDisplayView = new SurfaceView(this);
        setupPreviewDisplayView();
    }
    private void setupPreviewDisplayView() {
        previewDisplayView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(R.id.preview_display_layout);
        viewGroup.addView(previewDisplayView);
        gestureView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gestureView);
        previewDisplayView
                .getHolder()
                .addCallback(
                        new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                                processor.getVideoSurfaceOutput().setSurface(holder.getSurface());
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
                                Size viewSize = new Size(width, height);
                                Size displaySize = cameraHelper.computeDisplaySizeFromViewSize(viewSize);
                                converter.setSurfaceTextureAndAttachToGLContext(previewFrameTexture, displaySize.getWidth(), displaySize.getHeight());
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                                processor.getVideoSurfaceOutput().setSurface(null);
                            }
                        });
    }
    
    private void startCamera() {
        cameraHelper = new CameraXPreviewHelper();
        cameraHelper.setOnCameraStartedListener(
                surfaceTexture -> {
                    previewFrameTexture = surfaceTexture;
                    // Make the display view visible to start showing the preview. This triggers the
                    // SurfaceHolder.Callback added to (the holder of) previewDisplayView.
                    previewDisplayView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                });
        cameraHelper.startCamera(this, CAMERA_FACING, /*surfaceTexture=*/ null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you add the `SurfaceView` by code which will place it at the end of the views hierarchy. This means that it will cover all other views below itself. Placing it at the first place all views on top still can draw thier interface. Try this:
`viewGroup.addView(previewDisplayView, 0);`  -> 0 means add the view at the first position.

Comment: Yes thanks. It works. Can you answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the `SurfaceView` by code which will place it at the end of the views hierarchy. This means that it will cover all other views below itself.

Placing it at the first place, all views on top of your `SurfaceView`, can still draw their interface.

By using the [`addView` method overload where you can set the index](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#addView(android.view.View,%20int)) you're able to place your `SurfaceView` at the first place.

Therefore change your code from:

```
viewGroup.addView(previewDisplayView);
```

to:

```
viewGroup.addView(previewDisplayView, 0); // -> 0 means add the view at the first position
```